# Projectiles not killing player ship?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I added this script to the enemy ship and tried using it on the player ship but the projectiles still do not shoot and kill the player ship. I trying to get the laser guns on the enemy ship to kill the player ship. But my script is not working.  in the inspector in Unity, I needed to add the player ship to public Rigidbody projectile; so I did when trying to add the script to either or the enemy ship or player ship the enemy laser bullets still don't kill the player ship. But the enemy ship and its bullets follow the player ship though so that works. Any insight is welcomed :/

```
     using System.Collections;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using UnityEngine;

     public class Projectiles : MonoBehaviour
     {
     public Transform playerShip;
     public float range = 20.0f;
     public float enemyGunImpulse = 10.0f;
      bool onRange = false;
     public Rigidbody projectile;


    void Start()
    {
    float rand = Random.Range(1.0f, 2.0f);
    InvokeRepeating("Shoot", 2, rand);

    }
    void Shoot()
     {
    if (onRange)
    {

     Rigidbody enemyGun = (Rigidbody)Instantiate(projectile, transform.position + transform.forward, transform.rotation);
                          enemyGun.AddForce(transform.forward * enemyGunImpulse, ForceMode.Impulse);

        Destroy(enemyGun.gameObject, 2);
    }
}

    void Update()
    {
     onRange = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, playerShip.position)   < range;

    if (onRange)
        transform.LookAt(playerShip);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Create bullet, destroy bullet, wonder why no bullets...

Comment: Your right I will remove the bullet from the bullet.GameObject Thank you :)

Comment: There is nothing in the code that seems to talk of killing the ship, no ship.health-- or anything..

Comment: I got it to work  Thank you for your feedback working player health to keep alive longer in the game currently the player dies right away.

Comment: I updated my code now I combined the projectiles.s with the enemy management.cs I get no errors in Unity but the enemy bullets no longer kill the player ship. Any feedback is as always welcomed :)

Comment: I solved it I updated my code.